# Are intentionally misleading answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696815/how-to-convert-a-string-of-numbers-into-integers) has a funny, funny answer ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg41K.jpg)).  It is meant to be a joke and certainly not a proper answer to the question.  As the comments reveal, none of us hope that the answer or anything like it end up in any production code.  However, it has a positive score (though not the top score among answers).

Again I love the answer, but I somehow feel that SO is the wrong place for answers of this type.  Are we to just allow the voters decide, or is greater action needed against this type of answer?

Comment: But that answer is perfectly fine for Enterprise-grade software. :P

Comment: Meta-effect in the works: that answer received (currently) 12 more upvotes (from a previous score 2).

Comment: Ugh, I didn't account for the Meta-effect

Comment: Answer seems to be deleted now, so does any 10k user want to edit in a screenshot so the rest of us could at least see the joke? :)

Comment: @ivarni it's not deleted and I don't see any deletion in the post history. Here's a [direct link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3696871/3764814) just in case.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It seems I've completely failed at scrolling down on a webpage. I shall hang my head in shame :)

Comment: Before we worry about the answer, is that _question_ one we want to keep around?  (We can always move the joke to a better question, so don't let that affect your decision.)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Both the question and answer is deleted now (including your link) :(

Comment: @karma_geek I made a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/BNIN8qV.jpg) and added it to the question. Looks like we really hate fun :-\

Comment: Makes me wonder. What is the real shame? That someone posts a *working* over-engineered example as a joke, or that apparently there are more people willing to sabotage the system by upvoting it than there are to work with the system by downvoting it. Audit failed.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Thank you!

Answer (score 30):

Well, since [we hate fun](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), I have to agree.  Joke answers are not appropriate for Stack Overflow, and definitely shouldn't be upvoted.  They could mislead people, and detract from the value of the question/answer format.

We have a [site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) that is much more appropriate to this sort of humor, and will often get upvotes!

Comment: Codegolf is not really the place for fun at all either...

Comment: With the right tags!  (And I play code-golf the way real golf is played: against myself, ignoring all of the silly languages.)

Comment: This answer is very similar to the "code trolling" genre that's been thoroughly rejected on PPCG; I'm not so sure it would fly there either.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest code trolling was okay over there.  I meant to suggest that code humor is often appreciated.

Comment: That blog post continues to be one of Jeff's worst ever written. There's nothing that harms a community more than a policy which, by design, is randomly enforced for random reasons.

Comment: Maybe a "Code disscussion" site, or "Stack overflow discussion" should be setup?

Comment: @AJFarmar That's not really what the network is for.

Comment: They do [have some fun on Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/most-creative-way-to-display-42/21857#21857) (officially "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf").

Answer (score 4):

This should be deleted.

StackOverflow is about questions and answers. This is in no way an appropriate answer to this question.

It's definitely an absolutely hilarious answer, but this isn't a joke site. This kind of content does not belong here.

Honestly I'm very disappointed in the community that such an answer exists and [has gotten 33 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965/flyswat?tab=reputation) so far today from the meta effect.

Comment: And now the whole question is deleted, so I'm disappointed that, as usual, I can't see what all the fuss was about.

Comment: @Michael The question was asking how to convert a string of (comma-seperated?) numbers into (an array of?) ints I believe. The answer was a joke, making fun of "enterprise-grade software," which can overuse design patterns and be overly scalable. They gave an overly complicated answer (similar to [Enterprise Quality FizzBuzz](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition)), which used Factory and Builder design patterns and such to do that very simple task. That said, I don't have 10k rep, so I can't see it either. This is from memory.